# Visual Studio 2013 & Node.js: Stop debugger from opening chrome

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, debugging

How can I stop Visual Studio from opening chrome when I begin debugging my node.js app <kbd>F5</kbd>? The http request chrome sends crashes my app, which is very annoying.

[image]

<sup>Project settings</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I removed the value under Node.js port option.